# Importing headers and data into HTML table from SQL database

Tags: php, html, sql

In short, what I’ve been trying to implement over the last week or so is to retrieve data from an SQL table and insert it into specific columns of an HTML table. It’s been done, I know, I’ve browsed a bunch of forums, manuals, and videos but haven’t found anything that answers my problem.

What I want to do is create a table such as the one below:

[image: html table]

A brief explanation is: A user inputs a date when they want to make an appointment. The SQL table retrieves both the user-selected date in addition to 3 days before and 3 days after the select date (in this case the user selected Wed, Dec 6-17). The header represents the day and the time slots below represent the available time slots that are bookable on that day (this goes up to 17:00). In the case that a time slot isn’t available it shouldn’t be shown there, rather it should be replaced by the next available time slot.

This is the (non-functioning) php code:

```html
<?php
require 'connection.php';
$conn = Connect();

$sql1 = 'SELECT DATE_b FROM daysofweek';
$query1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);

$sql2 = 'SELECT TIME FROM daysofweek';
$query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
?>

<table class="bookAppointment">
  <thead>
      <?php
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
        echo '<tr>
                <th>'.date('D, M d-y',strtotime($row['DATE_b']) ).'</th>
              </tr>';
        }
      ?>
  </thead>
      <?php
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$row['TIME'].'</td>
              </tr>';
        }
      ?>
    </table>
```

And the result is that each header prints vertically (one under another) and I would like the headers to print horizontally.

What has mostly been covered by other resources is that the table headers have to be fixed – as in not from the SQL database. However, in this case I also need these headers to be pulled from the database in addition to the time slots that belong to each date.

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated. Even if it is just pointing me in the direction where I could read up more about how I could make php code do this or if this is an issue with the database design.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may remove the <tr> and place it outside your while loop or  check the last id in your table and make a for loop in php to make the code a lot cleaner

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that in your `while` loop you're looping over your rows in addition to your columns; each time the loop is run, a new row is created.

You currently have:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
    echo '<tr>
            <th>'.date('D, M d-y',strtotime($row['DATE_b']) ).'</th>
          </tr>';
}
```

Which outputs:

```
<tr>
  <th>One</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Two</th>
</tr>
```

In order to have your header cells all on the same line, you simply need to bring your `echo` of `<tr>` outside of your `while` loop:

```
echo '<tr>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
    echo '<th>'.date('D, M d-y',strtotime($row['DATE_b']) ).'</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';
```

Which will result in:

```
<tr>
  <th>One</th>
  <th>Two</th>
</tr>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks @Obsidian Age for the step by step description of what I was doing wrong. That's really helpful! I've been able to fix up my code now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not a direct answer featuring your original code the following ought to give you a clear idea how you could achieve the stated goal.

In this code the arrays `$rsdates` and `$rstimes` would be taken by querying the database and iterating through the respective recordsets - in fact the times needn't be drawn from the database at all - you could use the `range` as shown.

```
$html=array();
$rsdates=array('Mon','Tues','Wed','Thurs','Fri');
$rstimes=range( 09.00, 17.00, 0.5 );


$html[]="<table border=1 width='100%' cellpadding='1rem' cellspacing='1rem'>";
$html[]="<tr>";
foreach( $rsdates as $date ){
    $html[]="<th>$date</th>";
}
$html[]="</tr>";

foreach( $rstimes as $i => $time ){
    $html[]="<tr>";
    foreach( $rsdates as $index => $header ){
        if( is_float( $time ) ){
            list( $hour, $min )=explode( '.', strval( $time ) );
            if( $min==5 ) $min=30;
        }
        $html[]="<td id='day_{$index}_time_{$i}'>".date('H.i',mktime( $hour, $min, 0, 1, 1, date('Y') ) )."</td>";
    }
    $html[]="</tr>";
}

$html[]="</table>";


echo implode( PHP_EOL, $html );
```

By assigning an ID to the table cell you ought to also be able to identify which day/time is clicked ( assuming some javascript interaction )

This generates the following HTML table
[image]

Comment: Thanks @RamRaider. That's a really good solution and helps me understand PHP better!

Comment: Good - glad it helped. I realise though that you would probably want to add data from the database to this table?